# Drop Down Menu Not Dropping Down

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've got a CSS dropdown menu at http://intranet.turtle.com/ and the sub menus won't drop down. I started with a Weebly template and have been recoding it relatively free-hand, which I'm pretty new at, so I'm not sure what exactly caused the break. Was wondering if you guys could spot anything I can't.Thanks so much in advance for the help!

```
/* Nav */
.nav {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 10;
}
.nav ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 1000px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
.nav li > a.wsite-menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;

}
.nav li#active > a.wsite-menu-item,
.nav li > a.wsite-menu-item:hover {
  background: @navHover;
  color: white;
  border: none;

}
.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Subnav */
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: #00a5db;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  z-index: 10;

}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  background: @navHover;

}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow {
  color: transparent;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 0;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow:before {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  content: '\203A';
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 11px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu works fine on the internal pages... but it seems the html markup for the dropdowns (#wsite-menus) is missing on the homepage.